# Matlab swapping

Tags: string, matlab, vector

If I am given a string of letters `'abcd'` and I want to convert this to a vector of numbers `V = [1,2,3,4]` which corresponds to the position of letters in the alphabet table, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Just subtract 'a'. Add one to map 'a' to 1. The subtraction sends the results into a double.

```
V = C - 'a' + 1;
```

For example,

```
C = 'helloworld';
C - 'a' + 1
ans =
     8     5    12    12    15    23    15    18    12     4
```

Comment: +1 I thought that might work, but I wasn't at a machine with MATLAB to test it.

Answer (score 1):

To map 'a' to 1, 'b' to 2, etc., use the [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/double.html) function to recast the character back to its ASCII code number, then shift the value:

```
V = double(charString)-96;
```

**EDIT:** Actually, you don't even need the call to DOUBLE. Characters will automatically be converted into double-precision numbers when you perform any arithmetic with another double-precision number (the default type for MATLAB variables). So, the following is an even simpler answer:

```
V = charString-96;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `uint8`, then subtract the char value of 'a', then push that onto a vector. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47856.html&http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=matlab+string+manipulation+access+char&btnG=Search)

Comment: Your link is broken